# Localize Validation Messages from XDocument.Validate()

Tags: .net, validation, localization, xsd, linq-to-xml

How can one localize the message returned from XDocument.Validate()? It appears to return messages in English for me.

The below snippet writes the message "The 'UndeclaredElement' element is not declared." but this will not be helpful for non English users.

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var xDocument = XDocument.Parse("<UndeclaredElement/>");

    var stringReader =
        new StringReader("<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'/>");

    var xmlSchema = XmlSchema.Read(XmlReader.Create(stringReader), (o, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Message));

    var schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemaSet.Add(xmlSchema);

    xDocument.Validate(schemaSet, (o, e) =>
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
    });
}
```

Comment: What is your current culture set to?

Comment: System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture shows that it is running under en-us

Comment: That would be the reason the message is in English...

Answer (score 3):

To localize messages from the XDocument.Validate(), one must do two things:

1. Set the current culture to the desired language:

   ```
   System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-fr");
   System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-fr");
   ```
2. Install the .net framework language pack (in my case version 4's pack is [found here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=3324))

Thanks to John for the quick pointer..